# Why the same css path is working for asp pages but not for content pages

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a folder in my web application where aspx page and content page both are there and master page is in root location. I am using the css path which is loading fine in firefox console for aspx page but the same path is not loading for content pages checked in firefox console. Due to that some of the boostrap functionality not working.
Below is the css path for aspx page

```
<link href="MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and same path is used for content page

```
<link href="MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Need help in this.

Comment: <link href="Folder/MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> Include Folder Name in CSS Path

Comment: So you try to load the same file from pages in different folders? Or is that an oversimplification of your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The browser resolves the href url in a relative manner. If it's located in the root, you can place "/" in the beginning of the path, like this:

```
<link href="/MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

this will instruct the browser look for the stylesheet in the root, regardless of the current page's relative path. But if you use a server-side technology, like ASP.NET, there's another way of specifying the application's root - "~/", in this case, though in this case you'd have to add runat="server" to the tag, so it would look like this:

```
<link href="~/MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I am using asp.net only and my css file is inside "pages" folder.So i used the css path in content pages which is also in same folder. <link href="~/Pages/MySheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> but again i am checking in firebug css console there it is showing two css loading with same name and that is failed also.

Comment: Tilde-slash, i.e. "~/" requires runat="server" attribute set in order to work.